# Achieving tf transpose in metal performance shader

Tags: ios, tensorflow, metal

What is the best way to achieve the following in Metal

`inputs_transposed = tf.transpose(inputs,(2,0,1))`

Thanks to hollemans, i know this needs to be a compute kernel but i am not sure how to write it. Has anyone made an attempt to transpose in metal when input has more than 4 feature channels.

Answer (score 0):

You want to transpose your data on-the-fly? Then you'll have to write a compute kernel indeed.

It would look something like this in Metal Shading Language:

```
half4 inColor = inTexture.read(gid);
half4 outColor = half4(inColor[2], inColor[0], inColor[1], 0.0h);
outTexture.write(outColor, gid);
```

Where `gid` points at the pixel that this particular kernel is working on.

To do this for more than 4 channels it's pretty much the same thing but now you have to read from / write to different texture slices in the kernel.

The above example shows your `(2, 0, 1)` transpose but hardcoded into the kernel. It becomes a bit more complicated when you want to transpose in an arbitrary fashion. In that case you need to pass the new channel order into the kernel using an `MTLBuffer`, and you'll need to figure out which channel index corresponds to which texture slice and so on.

I know this is still somewhat of a vague answer. I'll see if I can whip up an example kernel for this and add it to my Forge open source library. https://github.com/hollance/Forge

**Edit:** I added a simple transpose kernel to Forge: https://github.com/hollance/Forge/blob/master/Forge/Forge/TransposeChannels.swift

You use it like this:

```
let channels = 8
let perm: [UInt16] = [2, 4, 0, 5, 1, 7, 6, 3]
transposeKernel = TransposeChannelsKernel(device: device, 
                             featureChannels: channels, permute: perm)
```

And then you encode it like any other MPSCNN kernel:

```
transposeKernel.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, 
                       sourceImage: img0, destinationImage: img1)
```

Since it's a part of Forge it uses a bunch of helper code from that library. If you want to add it to your own project and not use Forge, you'll also have to copy that helper code.

**Edit 2:** From your comment below it seems like you don't just want to swap channels around, but entire axes, so this `TransposeChannels` object isn't going to very useful to you. Hey, at least I got to add some code to my library. :-D

Comment: thanks a lot !  Yes this is for more feature channels [1024 to be precise]. I would kill for an example.

Comment: Essentially, i am trying to change a 7 * 7 * 1024 MPSImage into 1024 * 7 * 7. Will really appreciate if this can be an example on forge.

Comment: After transposing [not sure if i did it right] we are getting this error/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalImage/MetalImage-61.5/MetalPerformanceShaders/Utility/MPSLibrary.mm:357: failed assertion `MPS internal error: could not create specialized function with name cnnConvGenF'. Have you seen this

Comment: By 7 * 7 * 1024 I assume you mean width = 7, height = 7, channels = 1024? And you want to transpose it to width = 1024, height = 7, channels = 7? That's a little weird and it's also not what my transpose kernel does (it just lets you swap channels). Maybe you could explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve here...

Comment: we are trying to do what  tf.transpose(inputs,(2,0,1)) would do in tensorflow. This is a YOLO model's implementation in tensorflow and you can see that in their fully connected layer, they first transpose and then flatten and then apply weights. https://github.com/gliese581gg/YOLO_tensorflow/blob/master/YOLO_tiny_tf.py   and especially this piece of code dim = input_shape[1]*input_shape[2]*input_shape[3]
   inputs_transposed = tf.transpose(inputs,(0,3,1,2))
   inputs_processed = tf.reshape(inputs_transposed, [-1,dim])

Comment: What `tf.transpose(inputs,(2,0,1))` does really depends on the shape of `inputs`. ;-)

I'm not really that familiar with YOLO, so I'm not sure why they transpose/flatten, but you might consider not transposing (and flattening) the data. Instead you'd transpose the *weights* for the FC layer. This shouldn't change the actual computation that is performed and it saves a lot of work for the GPU.